Pattern for locating an item in a GraphQL paginated connection
We have a large paginated list implemented as a GraphQL Connection.
We want to show one specific item by ID in the list together with some item before and item (like you would with a search).
We can't use the existing arguments from (the spec)[https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Arguments]: first, after, last, before as they are defined.
Our solution is to add a new, unofficial argument locate and re-use first and last to say how many item before and after should be fetched.
Then while browsing the Relay (which maintains the Connection spec) source code, I saw that they reserved arguments find and surrounds.
I couldn't find anything about those anywhere and they seem to be added 9 years ago while merging the FB internal repo with the public GitHub. Does somebody know more?
Is there some pattern in locating an item in a list in GraphQL?
